# Django parent link to child

Tags: django-templates

I have 2 models.

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class UniDoc(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    units = models.ManyToManyField(Unit, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

How I can get unidoc list on link ti unit in template?

Answer (score 0):

Django provides [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
u = Unit.objects.get(pk=1)
u.unidoc_set.all()
```

So in your template, if you have passed in `u` from above:

```
{% for i in u.unidoc_set.all %}
   {{ i.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have one block with link like <a href="{{ unit.title.url }}?unit_id={{ unit.id }}">{{ unit.title }} ({{ unit.phonebook_set.count }})</a></ul> and when I click on link I need get list in another block